# Reconhecimento de voz sem Grammar

Tags: c#, reconhecimento-de-voz

Tenho exemplo de utilização de da Microsoft Speech Api, porém todos exemplos de Reconhecimento de voz utilizam Grammar para reconhecimento somente do que foi pré definido, gostaria de se saber se sempre tenho que utilizar Grammars ou se existe alguma maneira de reconhecer texto plano?

Abaixo o exemplo com Grammar:

```
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"));

    sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();//Som capturado pelo microfone

    var estabelecimentos = new Choices("hotel", "restaurante", "cinema", "shopping");
    var locais = new Choices("Rio Grande", "São José do Norte", "Pelotas");


    GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
    gb.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    gb.Append("Buscar");
    gb.Append(estabelecimentos);
    gb.Append(new Choices("em", "no"));
    gb.Append(locais);

    gb.Append(new Choices("e", "ou"), 0, 1);
    gb.Append(locais, 0, 1);

    var g = new Grammar(gb);
    sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g);

    sre.EndSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(1000);


    sre.SpeechRecognitionRejected += Sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
    sre.SpeechRecognized += Sre_SpeechRecognized; ;
    sre.SpeechDetected += Sre_SpeechDetected;


    Console.WriteLine("Ouvindo");
    sre.Recognize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisei em diversos locais, li a documentação do Microsoft Speech Platform, e infelizmente não consegui reconhecer texto plano, na documentação porém consta um método no `GrammarBuilder, AppendDictation()`, que deveria funcionar para o que eu queria, porém achei questões na MSDN que também diziam que não funcionava e que a API é mais indicada para comandos e não textos longo.

O código com AppendDictation();

`gb.AppendDictation();`

[Link da documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378380(v=office.14).aspx)